# cannot move al content to any other register

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

i have to copy three inputs from register al to memory. but i don't know i cant. in another program i did this but in this it does not copy any input to any memory location. my code is (please tell me where the problem lies.
im using MASM

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA 
intial1 DB ?
string0 DB 0dh,0ah,'***********',0dh,0ah
        DB '***********',0dh,0ah
        DB '***********',0dh,0ah
        DB '***********',0dh,0ah
        DB '***********',0dh,0ah ,'$'
string1 DB '*** $'
string2 DB ' ***$'
string3 DB 0dh,0ah,'***********',0dh,0ah
        DB '***********',0dh,0ah
        DB '***********',0dh,0ah
        DB '***********',0dh,0ah
        DB '***********$'
.CODE
MAIN PROC
mov ah,2
mov dl,'?'
INT 21h

;INPUT INTIALS

mov ah,1
INT 21h
mov bl,al
mov ah, 1
INT 21h
mov bh, al
mov ah, 1
INT 21h
mov intial1, al ; error lies here 


;DISPLAY

mov ax, @DATA
mov ds, ax
lea dx, string0
mov ah, 9
INT 21h
lea dx, string1
mov ah, 9 
INT 21h
mov ah,2
mov dl, bl
INT 21h
mov ah,2
mov dl, bh
INT 21h
mov ah,2
mov dl, intial1
INT 21h
lea dx, string2
mov ah, 9
INT 21h
lea dx,string3
mov ah,9
INT 21h

;ENDING

mov ah, 4ch
INT 21h
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: _"`; error lies here`"_ And what exactly is the error? Include the exact error message you're getting if it's a build problem. Or if it's a runtime problem, describe what's happening and how you've come to the conclusion that that particular line is causing the problem.

Comment: that's was a runtime error. I solved it by considering the @rkhb answer

Answer (score 1):

`mov intial1, al ; error lies here` needs also a correct initialized `DS`.

Place this block

```
mov ax, @DATA
mov ds, ax
```

at the very beginning of the `MAIN` procedure.